# Creating a scoreboard in windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello I am doing this project where I have to make a quiz with 50 questions and since I'm very new to programming overall, what is some way that I could make it so that when the right radiobutton is checked and the Next button is pressed add 1 to the score and then at the end show your total score.

Comment: Why don't you take a stab at it?

Comment: @GrantWinney Hi I havent tried anything since i have no clue of how to create a way to keep your score in 50 diffrent Forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a shot, this isn't a difficult but if you're totally lost and looking for a bit of a push...

- Create an empty form.
- Place some some controls on the empty form the way resembling the way you want it to look.
- Then add a click event handler to the next button.
- Test to see which radio button is on and then increment the score if it is the correct one.

Comment: Hi i knew that that is the way i had to do it but what is the actual code you type in?

Comment: Well we could do that but that would be the equivalent of plagiarism and you wouldn't be learning very much.  Programming is fun and the community is here to help you, but I don't think you'll find many people who will do it for you (for free).